# What is wrong with this URL for AVAudioPlayer in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I tried to create AVAudioPlayer like this

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/preview-public/project/e45d3194bb7f4768984fd53acc833600/fa13293c27314b448a815ebd42176684/audio-gnvY.m4a")!
do {
  let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
} catch (let err) {
  print("err", err)
}
```

I get this error: `Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=2003334207 "(null)"`.

I also tried

```swift
do {
  let _ = try url.checkResourceIsReachable()
} catch (let err) {
  print("err", err)
}
```

and I get this error: `Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=262 "The file couldn’t be opened because the specified URL type isn’t supported."`.

I can't figure out what could possibly be wrong with the url.

Images load normally from same bucket although if I check `checkResourceIsReachable()` on image URL it returns same error. (But I load image with `CGImageSourceCreateWithURL(url as CFURL` which might not have same checks as AVAudioPlayer.) Anyway I'm lost. Any ideas?

Comment: hi, URL working form your phone browser?

Comment: Is this link accessible from your phone/Mac? I tried wget which return 403 - Forbidden. Tried with ffmpeg also return 403. If you enter the link in chrome/safari, you get an error with code `UserProjectAccountProblem ` and message `User project billing account not in good standing.` You might want to check your account

Comment: URL works in browser, I've modified bucket name, so real bucket name is `preview-public`. I'll edit my post.

Answer (score 1):

AVAudioPlayer is for local `file:` URLs only. It doesn’t accept remote URLs, which would need to be streamed. For that, use AVPlayer.

Answer (score 1):

i have demo in try to run this code audio is working perfect

```
 let audiourl = URL(string: "https://storage.googleapis.com/preview-public/project/e45d3194bb7f4768984fd53acc833600/fa13293c27314b448a815ebd42176684/audio-gnvY.m4a")
    let player = AVPlayer(url: audiourl!)
    let playViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
    playViewController.player = player
    self.present(playViewController, animated: true){
        playViewController.player!.play()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In AVAudioPlayer, URL is the path to a local file.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url